# Finding a Perfect Square efficiently

Tags: algorithm, square-root

How to find the first perfect square from the function: `f(n)=An²+Bn+C`? B and C are given. A,B,C and n are always integer numbers, and A is always 1. The problem is finding n.

`Example: A=1, B=2182, C=3248`

The answer for the first perfect square is n=16, because `sqrt(f(16))=196`.

My algorithm increments n and tests if the square root is a integer nunber.

This algorithm is very slow when B or C is large, because it takes n calculations to find the answer.

Is there a faster way to do this calculation? Is there a simple formula that can produce an answer?

Comment: If I were you I would ask this in the math stackexchange.

Comment: Maybe one for http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 11):

What you are looking for are integer solutions to a special case of the general quadratic Diophantine equation<sup>1</sup>

```
Ax^2 + Bxy + Cy^2 + Dx + Ey + F = 0
```

where you have

```
ax^2 + bx + c = y^2
```

so that `A = a, B = 0, C = -1, D = b, E = 0, F = c` where `a`, `b`, `c` are known integers and you are looking for unknown `x` and `y` that satisfy this equation. Once you recognize this, solutions to this general problem are in abundance. Mathematica can do it (use `Reduce[eqn && Element[x|y, Integers], x, y]`) and you can even find one implementation [here](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/QUAD.HTM) including [source code](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/quad.java) and an explanation of the [method of solution](http://www.alpertron.com.ar/METHODS.HTM).

<sup>1</sup>: You might recognize this as a [conic section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#Cartesian_coordinates). It is, and people have been [studying them for thousands of years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section#History). As such, our understanding of them is very deep and your problem is actually quite famous. The study of them is an [immensely deep and still active area of mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_curve).

Comment: You may also want to add a link to a pdf on [Solving the generalized Pell equation](http://www.jpr2718.org/pell.pdf)

Comment: Jim and Jason, thanks a lot for your help, your answer were very helpfull